# css class id conflict

Tags: css

I'm new to css. Here's my html

```
<a href="#" class="clickme" id="noteaddbutton"> Add Note</a>
```

The class "clickme" is part of a jquery function and the id is supposed to change the size from the standard of other links but it isn't making the text smaller.

```
#noteaddbutton{
    font-size:13px;
}

a:link{
font-size:18px;
text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: An `#id` selector has the greatest specificity of any of the selectors IIRC. This should work.

Comment: What browser are you using? The text is 13px big for me in Chrome 16.

Comment: Chrome. Travis J was right, the class was taking precedence. It's working now.

Comment: The class shouldn't take precedence, as @alex said

Comment: @alex Yes, but I think certain browsers disregard that information and go by what elements are above other elements in the CSS...

Comment: @Charlie Do you know which, of any, do that?

Comment: Whatever browser he is using :D Firefox and Chrome seem to work (from the comments), and I'm not sure about Safari and the multiple version of IE. I have a feeling IE is the problem though.

Comment: @Charlie *I've* never seen that problem in IE.

Comment: If you see this in an IE that isn't the one installed by default (I'm thinking about Multiple IE and alike), then use the VMs that Microsoft is giving away for developers or the default IE. You're losing a lot of time with a tool that is *creating* problems when it should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a:link is taking precedence over #noteaddbutton.  Try using

```
a.clickme:link{ font-size: 13px;}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be with the CSS the OP posted.

Answer (score 3):

It is working for me. I am using FF8. You can try this.

```
#noteaddbutton{
    font-size:13px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS is read starting at the top and going down (**cascading** style sheet). The element you are attempting to style has the following qualities about it,

1. `<a>` tag
2. `#noteaddbutton`
3. `.clickme`

In your css, you are styling all `<a>` tags and `#noteaddbutton`, but the `<a>` style is after the style just for the ID. Since the ID style is before the `<a>` style, the `<a>` style takes precedence.

You can fix this by doing two things...

1.) Putting the ID styles below the `<a>` styles:

```
a:link{
font-size:18px;
text-decoration:none;
}

#noteaddbutton{
font-size:13px;
}
```

2.) Putting `!important` after the `font-size` attribute on the ID style

```
#noteaddbutton{
font-size:13px !important;
}
```

You can put #2 anywhere you like.

Comment: Whilst it is read top to bottom, that doesn't necessarily mean the rules are applied in that order. Specificity of selectors matters.

Comment: Do you mean that ID's take precedence over classes?

Answer (score 0):

Try making the class `!important` allowing it to take precedence:

```
a:link{
  font-size:18px !important;
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me, by example in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GFnK7/2/

First link is 13px and on yellow background for me (Fx9, WinXP).
The 2nd link has a dummy destination that you shouldn't have visited for now. I see it on lightgreen bg, 18px and then after a click on violet bg, if and only if `layout.css.visited_links_enabled` is set to true in `about:config`.
The 3rd link is identical to the 2nd one.

The pseudo-class :link applies to un-visited links. With a value of # for href, you'll soon have visited this URL ;) (after one click on any href="#" link)

Note: a selector with an `id` should be more specific than another selector with only a pseudo-class and an element (`:link` with `a`). This is (**1**,0,0) against (**0**,1,1) in terms of [selector specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity).